# Python - Conflict with Regex and Exclusive or Operator

Tags: python, operators

I'm importing `regex` for a word count in a string, and I'm trying to use the `^` operator. Although, the compiler is recognizing the `^` as part of regex, and not the exclusive or operator. This is my code:

```
import re as regex

count = len(regex.findall(r'\w+', question))


if count < 3:

    magicball.say("No Spam Allowed!!")

elif "will" in question ^ "can" in question ^ "did" in question ^ "is" in question ^ "do" in question ^ "are" in question ^ "has" in question ^ "does" in question ^ "is" in question:

    verified = True
    print(oringinalquestion)
```

The line that I'm getting the error is where it says `elif`. Basically, is there a way to tell the compiler that I want to use the exclusive or operator? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind your code?

Comment: I do not see any conflict in your example. Regex has nothing to do with your error.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add the error trace it would be great. My suspicion is that that you need to put brackets on every boolean statement like this:

```
elif ("will" in question) ^ ("can" in question) ^ ("did" in question) ^ ("is" in question) ^ ("do" in question) ^ ("are" in question) ^ ("has" in question) ^ ("does" in question) ^ ("is" in question):
```

Comment: It didn't work. The error is `unclosed string on line 10. Did you forget a quote?`

Comment: That would be because of a typo on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Operator `^` has higher precedence than operator `in`. Your expression is equivalent to `"will" in (question ^ "can") in (question ^ "did") ...`, while what you presumably want it `("will" in question) ^ ("can" in question) ^ ("did" ...`. So, use parentheses to disambiguate your expression.